# Bitmap PixelFormat properly detected only on second test

Tags: c#, bitmap, imaging, pixelformat

I need a screenshot saved in a Bitmap with PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb. I wrote a simple class and test like below:

```
public class CaptureScreenInfo
{
    public Bitmap TakeScreenShot(int posLeft, int posTop, int posRight, int posBottom)
    {
        int width = posRight - posLeft;
        int height = posBottom - posTop;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);

        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
        }

        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void RegularScreenShot()
    {
        CaptureScreenInfo csi = new CaptureScreenInfo();
        Bitmap bmp = csi.TakeScreenShot(0, 0, 800, 600);

        Assert.AreEqual(System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, bmp.PixelFormat);
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that if I change the PixelFormat to something else then the desired Format24bppRgb, first test will ALWAYS pass and only on the second test (and every test after that) I will get a fail. Similary if I change back to Format24bppRgb, first test will fail, and next tests will pass.

Any idea why?

**EDIT**: As per Luaan's comment I changed the code to be copy/paste-able. Obviously you will need to add all necessary references yourself.

Comment: This doesn't look like your actual code, and it doesn't display the issue you are facing. You need to add a minimal complete example that actually has the issue you need help with.

Comment: Are you sure your project references are in order? It sounds like the versions of your test DLL and the actual DLL are out-of-sync.

Comment: Code is now complete, ready to copy/paste (you need to add references and unit test obviously). As for issue not being displayed, there is nothing to display here. Description above is the only thing that can be provided.

Comment: @Luaan Hmm... not 100% what you mean by out-of-sync. Reference version numbers are matching if that's what you mean.

Comment: Try rebuilding the whole solution twice and then run the tests.